# How to list shipping methods on NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to list Ship Items (UPS, FedEx, etc..) via API. As it shows in [Accounting > Shipping Items > List](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/common/item/shipitems.nl).

The documentation for the [ItemFulfillment Record](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/SchemaBrowser/transactions/v2013_2_0/sales.html#tranSales%3aItemFulfillment) suggests that I use the operation **GetSelectValue** to list the shipMethod possible values (same as Ship Items).

The documentation for **GetSelectValue** ([page 125](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/partners/integration/download/NetSuiteWebServicesPlatformGuide_2_5_0.pdf)) describes the SOAP request I need to use:

```
  <env:Body>
    <platformMsgs:getSelectValue>
      <fieldName fieldType="sales_salesOrder_shipMethod"/>
    </platformMsgs:getSelectValue>
  </env:Body>
```

But it's not working, it seems that the **fieldType** is wrong.

```
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
      <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: fieldType not found on {urn:core_2013_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}GetSelectValueFieldDescription</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">partners-java10005.bos.netledger.com</ns1:hostname>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
```

Where can I find the correct **fieldType** to get a list of the Ship Items?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this post, I was able to come up with a C# solution.

```
var methods = new Hashtable();
var shipMethodFieldDesc = new GetSelectValueFieldDescription()
{
    field = "shipmethod",
    recordType = RecordType.estimate,
    recordTypeSpecified = true
};

// make connection.    

var result = connection.Service.getSelectValue(shipMethodFieldDesc, 0);
if (result.status.isSuccess)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < result.totalRecords; i++)
    {
       // cast to RecordRef 
       var itemRef = (RecordRef)result.baseRefList[i];

       methods.Add(itemRef.internalId, itemRef.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should there be a link to another post in here somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
<soap:Body> 
    <platformMsgs:getSelectValue> 
      <platformMsgs:fieldDescription> 
        <platformCore:recordType>salesOrder</platformCore:recordType> 
        <platformCore:field>shipMethod</platformCore:field> 
      </platformMsgs:fieldDescription> 
      <platformMsgs:pageIndex>0</platformMsgs:pageIndex> 
    </platformMsgs:getSelectValue> 
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: But what was the issue? Please don't just post code without an explanation