# How to synchronise Netsuite shipping methods in PHP app by webservices

Tags: netsuite

I am new in Netsuite development. I want to list all the Netsuite shipping methods in my PHP application by webservices (using latest Netsuite PHP toolkit). I have searched a lot on this but did not found any thing, even on Netsuite website. Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows the XML that needs to be sent as the SoapBody, you need to send the equivalent using the PHP wrapper.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21371120/3696510